# How to round decimal

Tags: vb.net

I need to round up any value that is greater than 8 and round down value below 7. Example:
1.27 round to 1.25 
1.28 round to 1.30

Any help on how to achieve this in VB is appreciated.

Comment: In this particular case, multiply by 20 (1 / 0.05), round, then divide by 20 again.